# Family of sets which intersect isn't connected

Tags: general-topology

Find any family of sets $A_n$ such that $A_n$ are connected sets and $A_{n+1} \subset A_n$ and  $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$$ is not connected.

I tried find family of sets such that $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n = (-1,0) \cup (0,1)$$ Of course it isn't connected but I don't have any idea how find family of sets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can’t do it with subsets of $\Bbb R$: connected subsets of $\Bbb R$ are intervals, and the intersection of nested intervals is an interval or empty. You can, however, do it in the plane.

For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $$A_n=\left([0,1]\times\left(0\frac1n\right]\right)\cup\{\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle\}\;;$$ each $A_n$ is connected, but $$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}A_n=\{\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle\}\;.$$

Comment: @Brian M. Scott nice example. Now I would like prove that $$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}A_n=\{\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle\}\;.$$ Of course $(\forall n\in\Bbb Z^+)$ we have $\{\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle\}\  \subseteq \bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}A_n $. But how prove that $ \bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}A_n \subseteq \{\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle\}\ $ ?

Comment: @Tomek: If $y>0$, there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac1n<y$, and then $\langle x,y\rangle\notin A_n$.

Comment: Ok I see it but why it is reason to say that $$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}A_n \subseteq \{\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle\}\;?$$

Comment: @Tomek: Let $A=\bigcap_nA_n$. It shows that if $y>0$, then $\langle x,y\rangle\notin A$. It’s obvious that $\langle x,y\rangle\notin A$ if $y<0$, since in that case $\langle x,y\rangle$ isn’t in any of the sets $A_n$. For the same reason it’s clear that $\langle x,0\rangle\notin A$ when $x\notin\{0,1\}$. Thus, the only points that can possibly belong to $A$ are $\langle 0,0\rangle$ and $\langle 1,0\rangle$.